# How to draw(bgl) line while clicking point to point

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to draw lines like the Carve addon's *Line* option. It starts by left clicking, and it adds a dot. Then it stretches a line to the next spot you click. I want this exact behavior, even drawn the same way. I tried searching the the Carve addon code, but I can't tell what I need and what I don't.

[image]

Comment: Check out the operator_modal_draw.py template in the text editor which can be edited to give the above functionality.  Unfortunately it appears `bgl` is going to be dropped for blender 2.8.

Comment: Yeah, I know abot the template, I just don't get it. But that is mute now if they're dropping bgl. Thanks.